# Stored Procedure Not Create with dbo Schema

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have folder with stored procedures in my project so when installing application it reads the stored procedure file and executes it on the server.

The problem is when sp name has `dbo` schema (`CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure`) it doesn't create sp on server, whereas if it doesn't have `dbo` (`CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure`) it will create sp on the server

```
string sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
var smoServer = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(cn));
smoServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
```

is this because of a server configuration issue or something else ?

thanks

Comment: does it throw any error,can you keep a debug point and check ?

Comment: Could well be a permissions issue. What schema do they get created with?

Comment: @Simon it's dbo  and no it's not throwing any exception

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the user has the rights to create schema on the sql server. To create the dbo schema user should have rights.

Comment: yeah user is a dbowner

Comment: Try to create a proc with dbo schema in the sql management studio itself and check whether u are getting any error.